# How to determine the forced frequency response using Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, vibrations, laplace-transform

I would like to determine the forced frequency response of the following vibrating system using the Fourier transform method:

$$m\ddot{x} + c\dot{x} + k = f_0\sin(\omega t) \tag{1}$$

So by obtaining the Fourier transform of both sides of eqn. (1) I get:

\begin{gather}
\mathcal{F}\{m\ddot{x} + c\dot{x} + k \} = \mathcal{F}\{f_0\sin(\omega t)\} \\
%
\Rightarrow (-m\omega^2 + i\omega c +k)X(i\omega) = f_0\frac{\pi}{i}\left(\delta(\omega-\omega_0) - \delta(\omega+\omega_0)\right) \\
%
X(i\omega) = \frac{f_0\frac{\pi}{i}\left(\delta(\omega-\omega_0) - \delta(\omega+\omega_0)\right)}{-m\omega^2 + i\omega c +k} \tag{2}
\end{gather}

However, the result in eqn.(2) is far from the expected result that we can obtain with harmonic balancing of eqn.(1) which would be $$X(i\omega) = \frac{f_0}{-m\omega^2 + i\omega c +k} \tag{3}$$

Therefore, I would like to know where am I making a mistake in my logic behind this? I figure that regardless of weather harmonic balancing or Fourier transforms are used, I should be arriving at the result of eqn. (3)

Comment: There is no error - rather you need to better udnerstand the relation between Fourier transform and what you call *harmonic balancing*. Using the same notation for the two may be misleading.

Comment: Yes, that would be my expectation from an answer to this question.